# How to customize the API metadata of springdoc-openai?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, customizer

I'm trying to customize the [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/), make it can work with [my framework](https://babyfish-ct.github.io/jimmer/docs/preface), but I meet two problems.

## 1. How to treat methods that do not start with `is/get` as properties of Model?

If users use my ORM framework by Java language, the property getters in the entity interface can either start with `is/get` like a traditional Java Bean, or don't start with `is/get` like a Java record, for example

```java
@Entity
public interface Book {

   @Id
   long id();

   String name();

   int edition();

   BigDecimal price();

   @ManyToOne
   BookStore store();

   @ManyToMany
   List<Author> authors();
}
```

Here, the wording that does not start with `is/get` is used, which looks like a java record, not a traditional java bean.

However, doing this will cause swagger-ui to think that the model doesn't have any attributes. So I have to change the behavior of swagger.

After some research, I found that this behavior can be changed using `io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverter`, which is the most likely solution.

However, springdoc-openapi does not explain in detail how to use ModelConverter in the documentation. Ultimately, this goal was not achieved.

## 2. How to control the shape of dynamic objects in HTTP response?

My ORM is GraphQL-style, its entity objects are dynamic so that data structures of arbitrary shapes can be queried, just like GraphQL does. For example

```java
@RestController
public class BookController {

    @AutoWired
    private JSqlClient sqlClient;

    // Query simple book objects
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> books() {
        return sqlClient.getEntities().findAll(Book.class);
    }

    // Query complex book objects
    @GetMapping("/books/details")
    public List<Book> bookDetails() {
        return sqlClient.getEntities().findAll(
            // Like the request body of GraphQL
            BookFetcher$
               .allScalarFields()
               .store(
                   BookStoreFetcher.$.allScalarFields()
               )
               .authors(
                   AuthorFetcher.$.allScalars()
               )
        );
    }
}
```

- The first query returns a list of simple book objects in the format `{id, name, edition, price}`
- The second query returns a list of complex book objects in the format `{id, name, edition, price, store: {id, name, website}, authors: {id, firstName, lastName, gender}}`

Dynamic objects can vary in shape, and these are just two special cases.

I expect swgger to tell the client the shape of the object returned by each business scenario. So, I defined an annotation called `@FetchBy`. It should be used like this

```java
@RestController
public class BookController {

    private static final Fetcher<Book> BOOK_DETAIL_FETCHER = 
          BookFetcher$
               .allScalarFields()
               .store(
                   BookStoreFetcher.$.allScalarFields()
               )
               .authors(
                   AuthorFetcher.$.allScalars()
               );

    @AutoWired
    private JSqlClient sqlClient;

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> books() {
        return sqlClient.getEntities().findAll(Book.class);
    }

    @GetMapping("/books/details")
    public List<@FetchBy("BOOK_DETAIL_FETCHER") Book> bookDetails() {
        return sqlClient.getEntities().findAll(BOOK_DETAIL_FETCHER);
    }
}
```

1. Declare the shape of the complex object as a static constant.
2. The `@FetchBy` annotation uses the constant name to tell swgger the shape of the returned dynamic object.

After some research, I found that this behavior can be changed using `org.springdoc.core.customizers.OperationCustomizer`, which is the most likely solution.

However, I found that the schema tree of swagger is not consistent with the generic type definition tree in the java language. For example, Spring's `ResponseEntity<>` wrapper will be ignored by swagger and will be not parsed as a node of schema tree. Theoretically speaking, this ability of swagger can be customized infinitely, so the two trees may not always be consistent and difficult to analyze.

Comment: I don't know how you solved your problem but I had to create custom converter inherited from `io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverter` for my case, which was support of some scala types and case classes. It was kinda hard because of lack of documentation and weak internet trail, and I cannot post it as an answer, because it is not the answer to your particular problem, but if you are still battling this just let me know.

Comment: @dmitry not the original asker, but I have a use case that requires processing scala case classes too. Would you be able to share some more details on how you did this?

Comment: @FrankRiccobono I implemented ModelConverter for scala classes and created clauses for container types like options and such. Too much code for the comment but I can share what I have in other ways if you still need it

Comment: Yes, please do share if you can.